# Delay Netezza stored procedure execution

Tags: sql, netezza

Is there a function that would delay the netezza stored procedure execution??

I remember in sql server they have waittime()..I am looking something similary to this.

I need to delay the stored procedure execution for a couple of seconds.

Comment: Why are you trying to delay SP execution inside of netezza? Couldn't the tool that calls the SP do this?

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find the equivalent of `pg_sleep()` but you could always use a loop that waits for an end time

```
WaitEndTime TIMESTAMP;

WaitEndTime :=  now()+ interval '1000000 microseconds'  --1 second from now
LOOP
IF now()> WaitEndTime  THEN
EXIT; -- exit loop
END IF;
END LOOP;
```